# how to print the resultset data from javabean in jsp?

Tags: jsp, javabeans

her is my test jsp code and javabean db function code:

jsp:

```
<%

conn.init();
ResultSet rs = conn.selectProductById (request.getParameter("pid"));

while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("pid"));
}

}  

%>
```

javabean:

public ResultSet selectProductById (String pid) {

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        String query = "select * from product where pid = ? ;";

        pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement
        pstmt.setString(1, pid); // set input parameter
        System.out.println(pstmt);

        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            pstmt.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
return rs;
}
```

error:

```
type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server
```

The jsp code is try to get the resultset from the method of javabean but there is an error. how to fix it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing/disposing the resultset/statement/connection object so you need to return `Product` object reference or  `List<T>` instead of `ResultSet`.

For instance,

```
public class Product
{
   private int id;
   private String name;
   .....
}
```

............

```
public List<Product> selectProductById (String pid) {

 ...
 List<Product> list=new ArrayList<Product>();

 try {
   String query = "select * from product where pid = ?";
   .....
   while(rs.next())
   {
      Product item=new Product();
      item.setId(rs.getInt(1));
      item.setName(rs.getString(2));
      list.add(item);
    } 
  ....
  return list;
}
```

Comment: if the javaBean is application scope, will it consume so much resource if the object containing a resultset?

Answer (score 0):

In finally block, you are closing the result set and the connection objects and later returning the resultset obj. Try to return the resultset object in the try block.

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer that addresses the same potential fix